# UiLifecycleHelper class in facebook sdk

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am building facebook app for android following a similar tutorial from facebook.
Problem is here [Facebook Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/personalize/) they are using UiLifecycleHelper and its is not available in facebook sdk. Is that a bug ? Any help much appreciated.

Image attached[image: Class not available]

Regards

Answer (score 3):

This was newly introduced in the Facebook SDK for Android that we released yesterday. It is possible that you downloaded the beta version of the SDK.

Please take the link that Ali provided above, and then clean and rebuild your projects. There's a full getting-started guide for the new (final version of the) SDK here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Comment: Well, I did downloaded the new sdk, there are some issues inflating fragments. I have tried a lot and inflating fragment error keep coming.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Facebook Android SDK 4.x or upgrading from 3.x to 4.x then make a note that

> CallbackManager.onActivityResult replaces Session.onActivityResult and UiLifecycleHelper.onActivityResult. See Facebook Login for Android, Register a Callback.

So you won't find `UiLifecycleHelper` class there. More details - [Upgrading the Android SDK from 3.x to 4.x](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x)

Comment: Its 2 years old. @AniketThakur

Comment: Yup and I landed on this as first few google searches. Got confused at first so adding my findings here hoping it will be useful to rookies like me :)

Answer (score 1):

This class `import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;` is already there in `SDK version 3.0` that why no one is answering this. Downloat the latest SDK from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)

Comment: I just downloaded it from there for a check, just to help you.

Comment: direct link :-https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.zip

Comment: thanks for your time. let me download again. I downloaded just day ago

Comment: One more thing that i faced using the sample code is that, when i imported the sample project it gave me error `classNotFound`
**using latest version of ADT and eclipse** although every thing was setup correctly **manifest,build path etc** so i created a new project and add the sample code files in it and that solved this issue.

Comment: facebook-android-sdk-3.0 does not have FacebookActivity class.

Comment: Here is link for the latest SDK version and i think you are using 3.0.1b:-http://developers.facebook.com/android/downloads/

Comment: OK then you have realized that facebook SDK has no more `FacebookActivity` class and this classs `UiLifecycleHelper` is now available.

Comment: yes. now they are extending main activity with FragmentActivity instead of FacebookActivity